# Git. Work on existing repository without cloning it

Tags: git, github

Im kind of new to Git.
So, last week I pushed my files to Github. Then I reinstalled my system (Ubuntu), then I downloaded the files as a Zip archive, extracted them and continued working. Now I want to push the updated files but I am not sure how can I do it.
Plz correct me if I'm wrong, git init would create a new repo. But there is one already. And git clone would fork it (as if I wasn't the original creator of the repository. And I find this strange cause Im the only contributor to my small app), anyway, I tried to do that and it will give the error:

"fatal: destination path  already exists and is not an empty directory."

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`git clone` will **not** make a fork but just clone the content of your repository on your local disk. Here is a manipulation you can do :

```
$ cd your_unzipped_dir/..
$ git clone git@github.com:yourname/yourproject.git
$ cp -r your_unzipped_dir/* yourproject/
$ cd yourproject
```

Now you can `add`, `commit`, and `push` as usual.

Comment: I created a new folder and did what you said. Doing that on my "unzipped dir" would give the same error "not an empty directory". Thnx anyway, it worked.